# Error when encoding UTF-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I am trying to fetch text data from a website, but this code shows some error. Please let me know where is the error.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getportions(soup):

for p in soup.find_all("p", {"class": ""}):   
    yield p.text


def readpage(address):   
   page = requests.get(address)    
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
   output_text = ''
   for s in getportions(soup):
      output_text += s.encode("utf8")
      output_text += "\n"
   print (output_text)
   print ("End of article")
   fp = open("content.txt", "w")
   fp.write(output_text)
if __name__ == "__main__":
  readpage("http://yahoo.com")
```

The error is shown below:

> output_text += s.encode("utf8"). TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: `.encode` returns a `bytes` object. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MorganThrapp I am trying to write contents in a file

Comment: Do you maybe mean `decode`? Why do you think you need to do anything with `utf-8`?

Comment: @MorganThrapp if I make the object as string then it contains  unnecessary chracter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Python 3, all strings are natively in unicode, and you can specify the encoding when opening a file. You code could become:

```
def readpage(address):   
   ...
   output_text = ''
   for s in getportions(soup):
      output_text += s
      output_text += "\n"
   print (output_text)
   print ("End of article")
   fp = open("content.txt", "w", encoding='utf8')
   fp.write(output_text)
```

If you simply want to sanitize the text by replacing all non ascii characters with a `?` open the file that way:

```
   fp = open("content.txt", "w", encoding='ascii', errors='replace')
```

Comment: It shows error agin: return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03a3' in position 350: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @NARAYANCHANGDER: Cannot reproduce. Show the code that produces the error and the stacktrace. Utf8 is meant to be able to encode any unicode character...

Comment: @NARAYANCHANGDER: ... and I can confirm that I could successfully process `u03a3` (`Σ`)